# Using a for-loop to iterate through files, calculate parameters and save as a new table

Tags: r, for-loop, datatable, save, iteration

I'm a R-newbie and I want to use the for loop to iterate through .txt tables.

I have a list of lidar .txt files which are saved in a folder. I want to calculate parameters from them using different functions and finally I want to save the parameters for every .txt in one single table.

Here is the example code to show how it looks until now, where I have to load every .txt file seperatly:

```
library(VoxR)

plot_xyz <- read.table("C:/Users/plot_a.txt")
plant_vox <- vox(plot_xyz,res=0.1)
plant_vox_filt <- subset(plant_vox, nbpts > 6)
horizontal <-VoxR::project(plant_vox_filt,dim="xy")
vegetation_grid <- nrow(horizontal)
vegetation_area <- vegetation_grid * 0.1^2
total_area <- 25*25
baumhoehe <- (max(plant_vox$data...3.) - min(plant_vox$data...3.))
gap_fraction_voxel <-  1- vegetation_area/total_area
lai_voxel <- - log(gap_fraction_voxel / baumhoehe)
```

Finally I want to create a result table which should give these parameters for every .txt file (rows).

```
  vegetation_area total_area baumhoehe gap_fraction_voxel lai_voxel
1          15       60            20         0.7          3.2
2          10       20            30         0.5          3.4
3          30       40            20         0.1          3.5
```

How can I use the for loop to achieve this? First I have to load the folder with the .txt to achieve something like this right?:

```
for (i in lidarfiles) {
plant_vox <- vox(plot_xyz,res=0.1)
plant_vox_filt <- subset(plant_vox, nbpts > 6)
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list.files` to get all the text files in the directory and include the code that you want to apply to each file in a function.

```
list_files <- list.files('C:/Users/', pattern = '\\.txt', full.names = TRUE)

get_result <- function(file) {
  plot_xyz <- read.table(file)
  plant_vox <- vox(plot_xyz,res=0.1)
  plant_vox_filt <- subset(plant_vox, nbpts > 6)
  horizontal <-VoxR::project(plant_vox_filt,dim="xy")
  vegetation_grid <- nrow(horizontal)
  vegetation_area <- vegetation_grid * 0.1^2
  total_area <- 25*25
  baumhoehe <- (max(plant_vox$data...3.) - min(plant_vox$data...3.))
  gap_fraction_voxel <-  1- vegetation_area/total_area
  lai_voxel <- - log(gap_fraction_voxel / baumhoehe)
  lai_voxel
}
```

Now using `lapply` apply `get_result` function to each file.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list_files, get_result))
```

Comment: Thanks! But somehow the result only contains the parameters of lai_voxel, even if I try to give back the other parameters at the end of the functions.

Comment: Since I don't have any data I can't test this. What other parameters do you want? You can add them in last line of the function with `lai_voxel`. Maybe something like `cbind(lai_voxel, other_data)` etc.

Comment: I also wanted to have parameters like gap_fraction_voxel in the table. But this approach helped, thank you!